# Using multiple version of jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two versions of jquery on same page using `$.noConflict()`. But older code is not working.

```html
<!-- load old jquery, add no conflict immediately after that  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict(true);
</script>


<!-- place where new jquery is loaded, add noconflict for the same -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var j1124 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script>
  //for new jquery
  j1124(document).ready(function() {
    j1124("#TxtBox").on("click", function() {
      console.log("on");
    });
  });


  $(document).ready(function() {
    //for old jaquery
    $("#TxtBox1").live("click", function() {
      console.log("live")
    });
  });
</script>


<h3>Page with issue. Old and new jqueries in use. Live not working</h3>
<div>
  <input name="TxtBox" type="text" id="TxtBox" />
  <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
</div>
```

My live function is not working. Please help

Comment: Instead of two separate versions, why don't you use jQuery Migrate? More info here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable#readme

Comment: I have create a snippet to reproduce the issue(removed not required parts)

Comment: jQuery.noConflict(true);